# How to use findModel in GXT 3.1.1?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

In GXT 2 I could do `store.find(property,value)` to find a model in the store. How do I do the same in GXT 3?

Most of the logics are done by this method in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are searching the store by key aka the `ModelKeyProvider`), you can use `Store.findModelWithKey` - simply pass it the key of the object you want, and you'll get the model that matches it.

If you are looking for any arbitrary key/value pair that is present on a model, why not just loop through the store until you find the right object with the matching property?